# Calculate the integral of $f(z) =\frac{z^2} {e^{\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}} }$ on $|z|=2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate the integral of $f(z) =\frac{z^2} {e^{(\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}) } }$ on $|z|=2$.

So since$ - i $ is an essential singularity I would have to find the Laurent series around $-i$. How do I do that since $e^{(\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}) } $ is in the denominator?
Any hint helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be easier if you write $$ f(z) =z^2 e^{-\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}}$$

Just use the Taylor series for $e^{-w}$ and substitute $w=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}$:
$$ e^{-w} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}w^n$$
$$ e^{-\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{1}{(z+i)^{2n}}$$
 Note that what you get is a Laurent series around $z=-i$ (covergent everywhere, because the Taylor series for $e^{-w}$ is covergent everywhere). Now you just need to multiply it by $$ z^2 = (z+i)^2 - 2i(z+i) - 1$$